# Virtual graph-paper software

Tags: gratis, drawing

Just a piece of graph paper but on my laptop.

Needed features:

1. List item
2. Grid snapping switch
3. Line tool
4. Curve tool
5. Different colors
6. Fill tool, not just for individual squares but also to fill shapes
7. Square tool (optional since i can draw one with the line tool)
8. Circle tool
9. Zooming and moving around the graph paper
10. Change size of the graph paper
11. Text tool (wich also needs to be able to snap to grid)
12. Copy, Cut, Paste, Undo, Redo, Delete
13. Save / Load
14. A bunch of extra stuff I'll probably never use but is handy to have just in case
15. Support for macro's (optional)
16. Support for plugins (optional)
17. Free

Even though it's not really 'free' I tried to use MS Excel 2010 which I had laying around but it lacked the ability to draw circles & curves that snap to the grid.

Comment: Any particular operating system?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Preferably Windows, But i can live with it being for Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Xfig](http://www.xfig.org/)

Xfig is a vector drawing program for Linux. It can be installed on Windows through [Cygwin/X](http://x.cygwin.com/), or you can use the freemium alternative [WinFIG](http://winfig.com/).

[image]

Features:

- Has a grid with customizable units
- Snap toggle for grid, endpoints, midpoints, and others
- [Line, curve, text, and shape tools](http://www.xfig.org/userman/frm_drawing.html)
- Colors and filling are not in a separate tool, but in the [object attributes](http://xfig.org/userman/attributes.html)
- Copy, Cut, Paste, Undo, Redo, Delete
- Save / Load to `.fig` files, and [export to many other formats](http://xfig.org/userman/printing.html#export)
- Expandable through object libraries
- Free of charge